# Is it possible to independently control checkboxes nested in a treeView?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, powershell, xaml

I have this code that outputs a treeview and each treeview item has a checkbox. Is it possible to have each checkbox renamed to reflect the content that it is showing.

```
<Grid>
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData},XPath=//@Name}">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="Check1">
               <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding XPath.}">
                  <StackPanel>
                     <ListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=..//@Foodname}">
                        <ListView.View>
                           <GridView>
                              <GridViewColumn Header="Selection">
                                 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                       <CheckBox Name="Check"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                              </GridViewColumn>
                              <GridViewColumn>
                              </GridViewColumn>
                           </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                     </ListView>
                  </StackPanel>
               </TreeViewItem>
            </CheckBox>
         </DataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

```
<Foods>
    <UnhealthyFoods Name ="Candy"/>
        <Food Foodname = "MMs" >
        </Food>
        <Food Foodname = "Skittles" >
        </Food>
        <Food Foodname = "Starburst" >
        </Food>
    </UnhealthyFoods>
    <HealthyFoods>
        <FoodGroup1 Name ="Vegetables"/>
        <Food Foodname = "Spinach" >
            </Food>
            <Food Foodname = "Brocolli" >
            </Food>
            <Food Foodname = "Greens" >
            </Food>
    </FoodGroup1>
    </HealthyFoods>
    <HealthyFoods>
        <FoodGroup2 Name ="Fruits"/>
        <Food Foodname = "Apples" >
            </Food>
            <Food Foodname = "Pears" >
            </Food>
            <Food Foodname = "Cherries" >
            </Food>
    </FoodGroup2>
    </HealthyFoods>
</Foods>
```

this is the xml data, I do not care for how it was written I am unable to make changes to it.

I tried using, but that errors out saying "You cannot call a method on a null valued expression.

```
[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$check_checked={param($sender,$e) write-host "testing"}

Check.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.Checkbox])::CheckedEvent,$check_checked)
```

So for fun I tried creating another checkbox in a different location that was not in the tree view and the above code did work.

Comment: ...I don't think it's a good idea to have a `<GridView>` inside a `TreeViewItem`...

Comment: What would you recommend instead @Dai

Comment: I can't make any recommendations without knowing what your `xmlData` looks like or what it represents.

Comment: Added xmldata, i am unable to make changes to it as i am not the owner. Just trying to manipulate it as is @Dai

Comment: Your XML is invalid: you have unencoded reserved characters like `&` in it, and your `<Food>` elements have both `/>` but also `</Food>`  - I know you said you can't make changes to it, but it's very, very invalid: you simply won't be able to load it at all: `XmlDocument` will throw. You're stuck until you fix that.

Comment: Removed the invalidations. The extra slashes and ampersand were error in translation and not a direct reflection of the actual xml code. The code has been rewritten to remove sensitive data those issues do not exist in the real code. With these changes how would I procede? @Dai

Comment: You haven't explained how you want to map each XML element to the TreeView - you have hetereogenous XML element types. Your WPF XAML's existing Data-Binding expressions don't correspond to your XML at all.

Comment: TreeView would be binded to name... TreeViewItem binded to "."... and Listview Binded to  ..//@Foodname

Comment: This is not how a tree structure works. You  must convert the XML data to a C# tree data structure first. In your example you would have three root-level nodes: UnhealthyFoods, HalthyFoods and HalthyFoods. then each root node has child nodes, the actual Food items. The data structure would be a source collection named Foods that you bind to the TreeView.ItemsSource. This collection contains three classes of type e.g. FoodCategory. FoodCategory exposes a child collection that contains the Food items.

Comment: Then you would define a HierarchicalDataTemplate as ItemTemplate to create the visual tree automatically. This is how it is done. You don't use a nested ListBox. That's wrong. So, first step is to deserialize the XML into a C# class: [How to deserialize an object using XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-deserialize-an-object). The map data to the structure using the HierarchicalDataTemplate [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [VisualTreeHelper Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper) to find all the checkboxes in your TreeView:

```
Public Function FindCheckboxes(container As DependencyObject) As List(Of CheckBox)
    Dim checkboxes As New List(Of CheckBox)

    For counter As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(container) - 1

        Dim child As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, counter)

        If child.GetType = GetType(CheckBox) Then
            checkboxes.Add(child)
        End If

        For Each childCheckbox As CheckBox In FindCheckboxes(child)
            checkboxes.Add(childCheckbox)
        Next

    Next

    Return checkboxes

End Function
```

You'd call this function once you tree is built and add your event handler to every checkbox in the List it returns.

Here's a sample of how it can be used to display a list of checkboxes in a `books` ListView:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim list As String = ""
    For Each checkbox As CheckBox In FindCheckboxes(books)
        list &= checkbox.Name & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox(list)
End Sub
```

In your case, you'd pass it your TreeView and check the IsChecked property of the CheckBox controls it returns.

If you wanted to change their Name, you could use the same function:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim checkboxes As List(Of CheckBox) = FindCheckboxes(foods)

    For Each checkbox As CheckBox In checkboxes

        If checkbox.Content IsNot Nothing Then
            If checkbox.Content.GetType = GetType(TreeViewItem) Then
                Dim item As TreeViewItem = CType(checkbox.Content, TreeViewItem)
                Dim attribute As XmlAttribute = CType(item.Header, XmlAttribute)
                checkbox.Name = attribute.Value
            End If
        Else
            Dim attribute As XmlAttribute = CType(checkbox.DataContext, XmlAttribute)
            checkbox.Name = attribute.Value
        End If

        Debug.WriteLine(checkbox.Name)

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: For my code specifically it returns "Check1" "Check" "Check" "Check" "Check1" "Check1". Which is the name of those specifically checkboxes, but I am wondering if it is possible to rename them dynamically based on how many items are in the list the treeview is called from

Comment: @netengineer8834 yes that's easy, just update the checkbox's Content property.. I updated my answer with code to do this.

Comment: I think I explained incorrectly. The end result I am looking for is to have each checkbox named based on the content it is showing. Ex. the MM's checkbox to be named MM's

Comment: @netengineer8834 You can already access the Checkbox's Content (`MM's`); what would having it named the same as the Content achieve?

Comment: That gives me the ability to call on them from powershell as they would have different names. As it stands right now they all share the same name which prevents me from controlling them.

Comment: @netengineer8834 see updated answer, I added code to rename the checkboxes based on their content. Since controls cannot have spaces in their names, I replace spaces with underscores. You will have to adjust your powershell code accordingly.

Comment: since the checkboxes content is "TreeViewItem" it throws the error, "Conversion from type treeview item to string is not valid"

Comment: @netengineer8834 so you convert Content into a TreeViewItem and get the information you need. I've updated my answer with that but you already have all you need.